# ERRO DE LÓGICA/FRAÇÃO EM PYTHON(COMO RESOLVER)

Tags: python, lógica

> Nesse código de caixa de mercado, caso digite 0 na variável pv irá haver um erro no ultimo print na variavel vp/pv, pois não há como caucular um numero x dividido por zero, como faço pra que caso a pessoa digite 0 não haja erro ?(resolver o problema com códigos ou lógica de matemática ok)

````
t = '---'
l = '    ' * 9
print(l, 'Caixa numérico')
p = float(input('Qual o preço ?R$'))
d = float(input('Desconto por cento:'))
pv = int(input('Se deseja parcelar, coloque em quantas vezes, se não, digite "1":'))
v = p - (p / 100) * d
vp = p + (p / 100) * (20-d)
print('\nO produto com valor de {}, sairá por {}R${:.2f}{} a vista no desconto de {}%'.format(p, t, v, t, d))
print('ou {}R${:.2f} parcelado{} em {}{}x de R${:.2f}{}, no desconto de {}%'.format(e, vp, e, e, pv, vp/pv, e, d-20))```
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar `if` e `else`

```
if Variavel == 0:

print("...")

else:

print("...")
```

Se você ainda não aprendeu `if` e `else` recomendo acessar https://www.devmedia.com.br/python-estrutura-condicional-if-else/38217 Para entender melhor.